# I don't know how i can run a function continuously on xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Hello this is my first time when i program in C# and first time when i use xamarin,and i maked this code  on xamarin as a first project.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Counter
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private int count = 0;
        private int squared = 0;
        private double sqroot = 0;
        private int milliseconds = 500;
        private bool direction = true;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void IncrementCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            direction = true;

        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            direction = false;

        }

        private void Auto_increment()
        {
            if (direction == true)
                count++;
            else
                count--;

            squared = count * count;
            sqroot = Math.Sqrt(count);
            CounterLabel.Text = count.ToString();
            Squared.Text = squared.ToString();
            Sqroot.Text = sqroot.ToString();
            Task.Delay(1000);

        }

    }
}
```

How can i run the function Auto_Increment every time the code executes?
I would use it on an android device, if it matters.
And also how i can display only first 2 digits of the double variable?

Comment: Just call the routine where ever you need it; it's not present where you want to at this point. Look into `string.Format` to get the format you need for displaying.

Comment: Call `Auto_Increment()` in your constructor `MainPage()`. Every time you launch your application it will execute your code.

Comment: @PhilippeB. if i put on mainpage, it will run it only once

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ i want it to run continously , to increment the count integer without any halp from me

Comment: I suspect that you mean you want it to run periodically on some time interval, not continuously.  If that's the case then you would use a Timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know If you want to use it for an android app which is build using xamarin you could actually use the lifecycle function given below:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    #CALL_YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE
}
```

and to round the double values you could use the round method which is given below:

```
Math.Round(#Value_to_be_rounded, #number_of_decimal_places)
For instance: Math.Round(3.56, 1) will give you 3.5
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i cannot call the function in void OnResume() because it sayes that the function doesnt exist in context

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. Note that this solution isn't a good one. You have to control this infite loop in `Auto_increment()` or find another way to run it continiously in a cleaner way. Add a new button and replace the `while(true)` with `while(yourBoolean)` that you control by clicking the new button (like you already do for the increment.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private int count = 0;
    private int squared = 0;
    private double sqroot = 0;
    private int milliseconds = 500;
    private bool direction = true;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Auto_increment();
    }

    private void IncrementCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        direction = true;

    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        direction = false;

    }

    private void Auto_increment()
    {
        while (true) {

            if (direction == true)
                count++;
            else
                count--;

            squared = count * count;
            sqroot = Math.Sqrt(count);
            CounterLabel.Text = count.ToString();
            Squared.Text = squared.ToString();
            Sqroot.Text = sqroot.ToString();
            Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

PS : Also note that you should follow the [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) in your code. In your case rename your private method `AutoIncrement()`.

Hope this will help you.